# OpenAPI client generator Java - header per call

Tags: java, http-headers, openapi

I have an API which serves public and private resources. User is expected to pass an authorization header while making call to private resources. Also the authorization header can rotate.

How do I specify the HTTP header per outbound RPC from generated Java client from OpenAPI specification files?

I tried multiple library options, all seem to have ability to specify set of header while initialization of the client. (but not per call, or not to rotate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the generator you can use an Interceptor to achieve this, for example with OkHttpClient:

```
final okhttp3.Interceptor authTokenInterceptor = chain -> {
        Request request = chain.request();
        Request.Builder requestBuilder = request.newBuilder();
        if(request.header(AUTHORIZATION) == null) {
            // needs bearer token, only if not already present
            requestBuilder.addHeader(AUTHORIZATION,"Bearer " + tokenSuppliedByAFunction());
        }
        
        return chain.proceed(requestBuilder.build());
    };

okhttp3.OKHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .addInterceptor(authTokenInterceptor)
    .build();
```

Although this is supplied at client creation time, you can write `tokenSuppliedByAFunction()` to dynamically add the desired token.

Comment: nice! how about passing a custom header per call?

Comment: I think by design that's not possible. Headers should be defined in the API spec, in which case they will be available to manipulate as parameters (optional or required depending on their definition), not added arbitrarily at runtime. However, as a hack you may be able to modify my example and detect whether a special header should be added based on other request properties, such as the URI.