# Pass Along Authorization Header in OpenAPI Generator-generated Java WebClient Code

Tags: oauth-2.0, spring-webclient, openapi-generator

I have a Java/Spring-based microservices architecture with two services:

- A - has a public-facing endpoint which does some stuff and then calls the below endpoint on B.  This endpoint requires an Authorization header (OAuth2) to identify the user.
- B - has an endpoint that also requires an Authorization header (OAuth2) so that it can determine which user made the call.

I have specified B's endpoint using OpenAPI.  I'm using OpenAPI Generator to generate both the client in A (Spring WebClient), and the server in B (Spring Boot).

My question is this: what do I need to do to pass the Authorization header along from A to B?  I see how to set a static header, but I don't know how to pass the header based on what's received by A.

Similar to this question, but for WebClient: [OpenAPI client generator Java - header per call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71344597/openapi-client-generator-java-header-per-call)

Comment: Is `A` a resource-server (REST API) or a client (server-side rendered UI with Thymeleaf, JSF or whatever) ?

Comment: Does [this tutorial](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_ui) help? Have a specifical look at what is done in [`UiController`](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/blob/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_ui/src/main/java/com/c4soft/springaddons/tutorials/UiController.Java)

Comment: A is a rest api resource server.

Comment: The problem lies in how do I pass a per-request header to an OpenAPI Generator generated class.  I believe the solution will have something to do with either the OpenAPI spec I created, or the OpenAPI Generator template I'm using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out my problem was how I specified the endpoint security in my OpenAPI specification.

I added:

```
components:
  securitySchemes:
    s2s:
      type: oauth2
      flows:
        clientCredentials:
          authorizationUrl: https://example.com/oauth/authorize
          tokenUrl: https://example.com/oauth/token
          scopes:
            read: Read scope
```

And made a reference to that security schema on my endpoint:

```
 /foo:
    get:
      ...
      security:
        - s2s:
            - read
```

Now, when I run `openapi-generate` on this schema and generate it to either Spring Boot (server) or Java WebClient (client), the generated endpoint signature looks like:

```
    @RequestMapping(
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        value = "/foo",
        produces = { "application/json" }
    )
    Mono<ResponseEntity<MyResponse>> foo(
        @Parameter(name = "Authorization", description = "", required = true) @RequestHeader(value = "Authorization", required = true) String authorization,
        @Parameter(hidden = true) final ServerWebExchange exchange
    );
```

The `String authorization` argument to the method was not previously being generated and it's what I needed here.  It allows me to pass A's header along to the call to B.

Props to @Ch4mp for helping out here.

Comment: I never thought to have original Authorization header injected directly. That's smart and simpler than retrieving it from Authentication instance. You should accept your own answer (maybe just specify for noobs that this `authorization` string should be used to set WebClient `Authorization` header in method body ;)

Answer (score 1):

As your `A` service is a resource-server and you want to issue request to service `B` on behalf of the user who initiated the request to `A`, just set a `Bearer` `Authorization` header on WebClient with the original access-token string retrieved from current security context (use `SecurityContextHolder` static accessor or have `AbstractOAuth2TokenAuthenticationToken<?> auth` auto-magically injected by Spring as `@Controller` method parameter).

If your `A` service was a client, you could do as I did in the [`UiController`](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/blob/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_ui/src/main/java/com/c4soft/springaddons/tutorials/UiController.Java) of [this tutorial](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_ui).