# How to forward tokens using the openapi java client generator

Tags: openapi-generator, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I would like to know the best practice to use the client generated by the `openapi-generator-maven-plugin` in the context of a Spring Boot application, where the application will communicate with an external API using the client, forwarding the user's token.

I don't see how it is possible to use the existing `@Autowired` functionality, which seems to assume that the bearer token is only configured once, e.g. by a `client credentials` flow.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74893267/pass-along-authorization-header-in-openapi-generator-generated-java-webclient-co) suggests that adding a security scheme to the endpoint will add another request parameter to the client. However that did not change the client.

There is an article that suggests [modifying the RestTemplate to add the bearer token](https://medium.com/@zomzog/openapi-generator-client-auth-token-management-683fce35ec30) however this doesn't appear ideal, as it affects the global `RestTemplate`.

Do I just have to drop the `@Autowired` functionality, and construct the client on a per-user request basis, in order to forward their tokens to the external API?

My `openapi-generator-maven-plugin` configuration:

```
          <plugin>
           <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
                <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${openapi-generator.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>Generate server</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/petclinic.yml</inputSpec>
                            <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                            <apiPackage>com.example.petclinic.api</apiPackage>
                            <modelPackage>com.example.petclinic.model</modelPackage>
                            <supportingFilesToGenerate>ApiUtil.java</supportingFilesToGenerate>
                            <configOptions>
                                <delegatePattern>true</delegatePattern>
                                <useSpringBoot3>true</useSpringBoot3>
                            </configOptions>
                            <configHelp>false</configHelp>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>Generate client</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                          <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/petclinic.yml</inputSpec>
                            <generatorName>java</generatorName>
                            <apiPackage>com.example.petclinic.client</apiPackage>
                            <modelPackage>com.example.petclinic.model</modelPackage>
                            <generateApiTests>false</generateApiTests>
                            <generateModelTests>false</generateModelTests>
                            <library>resttemplate</library>
                            <configOptions>
                                <useJakartaEe>true</useJakartaEe>
                                <generateClientAsBean>false</generateClientAsBean>
                            </configOptions>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding

```
    post:
      summary: Create a pet
      security:
        - bearerAuth: []
```

```
components:
  securitySchemes:
    bearerAuth:
      type: http
      scheme: bearer
      bearerFormat: JWT
```

And setting

```
<generateClientAsBean>false</generateClientAsBean>
```

In the latest version 7.0.1 of the `openapi-generator`

And creating an `ApiClient` `@RequestScope` bean seemed to work:

```
    @Bean
    @RequestScope
    public ApiClient apiClient() {
        Jwt principal = (Jwt) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient();
        apiClient.setBearerToken(principal.getTokenValue());
        return apiClient;
    }

    @Bean
    public PetsApi petsApi(ApiClient apiClient) {
        PetsApi petsApi = new PetsApi(apiClient);
        return petsApi;
    }
```